# Magic that's not magic and nuclear submarines

Tags: story-identification

The story I'm looking for is probably from the 70ies-80ies. I remember very little of it, they are more sensations and feelings than real plot... so I imagine it'll be difficult.

It starts in a village, between high mountains, with a lot of snow. There is a visit to a cozy, warm house of a "wizard" with some kind of crystal ball which really is a piece of old technology. I don't remember the story, just the image of the scene. The meeting was for an incipient war with neighbors, or something like that.

It ends in a kind of techno-modern war control center, or probably a submarine, where the main character is using an old, most unknown, technology to smash the enemies, and was questioning about the ethics of such a war, where you can't feel or see the "other" suffering, and feeling bad about it even if on his side.

That's it -- a couple of quite vivid images and no more. Can anyone remember something similar? It was probably printed on the Italian collection "Urania", because that was what my mother used to buy then...

Comment: Possibly Fred Saberhagen's [Empire of the East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_of_the_East_series).  Was the first novel(s) I thought of when reading the question

Comment: @Alith could be, but I'm not sure. Too much magic and I remember just a single novel, self-contained....

Comment: I've read that book, but the title hasn't stuck with me. The "crystal ball" is some sort of satellite viewer, embedded in the floor. The submarines are in Los Angeles.

Comment: The ending is kind of anticlimactic. >! When they get to the city, the citizens revolt and destroy the submarines themselves.

Comment: @AaronGullison you're on it --- the satellite viewer rings a bell. The ending too...

Comment: No longer at my local library. It was somewhere between M and S.

Comment: Your description reminds me of "Warlock", a 1972 science fiction novel by Dean Koontz.https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwixsaX65Oz6AhXlFVkFHT6eAQEQFnoECB4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodreads.com%2Fen%2Fbook%2Fshow%2F3335972&usg=AOvVaw1Bb_nBlmLMfr3i-5W85w4s This novel follows a type of wizard called a "Mover and Shaker" (his magic is really advanced psychic powers) from his mountainous village, across a far-future apocalyptic landscape in search of ancient technology. The novel climaxes with the hero's crew finding an advanced war submarine.

Comment: @StanleyWebb It was translated "Spedizione verso il Niente" in Italian, and the cover rings a bell — I indeed had read it. So it could be... Thanks! (And yes, it's it, your extended comment fits perfectly.) Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your description reminds me of "Warlock", a 1972 science fiction novel by Dean Koontz. This novel follows a type of wizard called a "Mover and Shaker" (his magic is really advanced psychic powers) from his mountainous village, across a far-future apocalyptic landscape in search of ancient technology. The novel climaxes with the hero's crew finding an advanced war submarine.

[image]

Comment: Which was in fact published in [Urania #733](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?380170).

Comment: Yes, this is definitely it. Thanks a lot!